# R Filter a dataframe by values in a column of type list

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame which has a column which has list in it. I want to filter the DF based on that list

```
id <- c(1,2,3)
type <- c("dog1|dog2","cat1|cat2","mouse1|mouse2")

df1 <- data.frame("id" = id,"type" = type)
str(df1)
df1$type <- strsplit(as.character(df1$type),"|", fixed = TRUE)
matchingL <- c("dog1","mouse2", "mouse1", "ant")

# this does not work
df1[unlist(df1$type) %in% matchingL,]
```

result is

```
     id       type
1     1 dog1, dog2
NA   NA       NULL
NA.1 NA       NULL
```

while I want the result to be

```
id       type
1       dog1
3       mouse1
3       mouse2
```

Comment: ````data.frame```` syntax requires that you add a comma after ````df1$type %in% matchingL```` inside the square brackets

Comment: Sorry. I have modified the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `?unnest` from the tidyr package to make a long dataframe with one row for every value in a list in `type`, then filter the rows using `%in%`:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df2 <- df1 %>% 
  unnest(type) %>% 
  filter(type %in% matchingL)

df2
#>   id   type
#> 1  1   dog1
#> 2  3 mouse1
#> 3  3 mouse2
```